Applink not working, despite assetlinks.json being available
I am struggling setting up my android app linking for a domain, which is not globaly available.
What I tried
The assetlinks.json-file is available, and correct (copied from play console):
[
    {
        "relation": [
            "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
        ],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.test.mydemoapplication",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
                "...:12"
            ]
        }
    }
]

The ApplicationManifest.xml also is not the issue, as the app links are correctly displayed in adb shell pm get-app-links, which displays:
  com.test.mydemoapplication:
    ID: ee****
    Signatures: [...:12]      /* note the matching signature */
    Domain verification state:
      mydemoapplication.com: 1024

I also restarted the verification process several times by running adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify com.test.mydemoapplication. I always end up with the error 1024.
File not reachable for Google:
In the play console, i receive the error Digital Asset Links JSON file failed. Add a Digital Asset Links JSON file to all the failed domains. Then it states the domain, which is available from my location.
The tool https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://mydemoapplication.com:port&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls also indicates, that it can not be loaded.
At this point I want to emphasize, that the assetlinks.json-file is available under https://mydemoapplication.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json from the browser of the smartphone I'm testing it on.
What I suspect
Somehow, the assetlinks.json-file must be served at a certain (geographic) location, that is not known to me. Against my believes, not my smartphone is verifying the app-link, but some server from google does.
While this itself is not an issue, this is a problem for my application, for which the website is only available in some (EU-)countries. I have successfully tested retrieving the assetlinks.json file with a vpn in all of the countries in which the app-bundle (and all previous app-bundles).
Help needed
I could not find documentation, on how the app-link verification process works. Any guidance towards such a resource would be highly appreciated. If there is a setting, or a way to bypass that supposedly "remote" app-link verification it would be best.
I would also be happy to receive feedback, whether my guess is plausible, or if I should look if I missed something somewhere else.

Just checking if you seen/tried: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#manual-verification

Hello, yes, I have. In particular this is where I get the error/status 1024
